# Dialogflow V2 Acesstoken

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Hi i'm moving my work from V1 to V2 on dialogflow but i'm having issues finding the accessToken

On v1 it was:

const app = new DialogflowApp({ request: req, response: res });

...

**const AccessToken = app.getUser().accessToken;**

But for v2 this won't work. Can anyone help?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

AccessToken was available in DialogFlow V1, in V2 Google cloud platform's service account is used for authentication. You can get detailed information here: [DialogFlow V2 Auth](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup)